# Understanding properties C#

Tags: c#, interface, properties, get, set

I'm doing a C# course now and going through the basics. I've been trying to understand properties and how exactly get and set work in C# but I keep confusing myself. I'm starting to get it I think, but I'd appreciate it if someone let me know how right/wrong I've got it.

I'm going to post an exercise I'm reviewing, about an application that will print rectangles. The point of the exercise is actually practicing with interfaces, but properties are the thing that is confusing me most of all

I've got the code for the Rectangle class here and I've put comments under some of the statements saying what I think is happening here. If anyone has any advice or guidance it would be greatly appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Interfaces_3
{
    class Rectangle : Scalable, Comparable
    {
        double width, height, scale = 1.0;

        public double Scale
        {
            get { return scale; }
            set { if (value > 0) { scale = value; } }
            /* the Scale property will take the scale field value 
             * will update the scale double in the Scalable interface,
             * but only if the value given to scale is positive*/
        }

        public double Width
        {
            get { return width * scale; }
            set { width = value; }
            /* using the value supplied by the user later,
             * width field will be set. this will then be multiplied by the scale 
             * field to get the value of Width property */
        }

        public double Height
        {
            get { return height * scale; }
            set { width = value; }
            /* height * scale will be read, and then the width field will
             * be set to the Height property? I think? */
        }

        public double Area
        {
            get { return Width * Height; }
            /* Width * Height is read 
             * there's no 'set' here because... not sure */
        }

        public Rectangle(double width, double height)
        //constructor
        {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public bool IsEqual(Object o)
        {
            if (o is Rectangle)
            {
                if (((Rectangle)o).Area == this.Area)
                /* if the Area of "o" is equal to
                 * the Area of the other specified object*/
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool IsGreater(Object o)
        {
            if (o is Rectangle)
            {
                if (((Rectangle)o).Area < this.Area)
                /* if the Area of "o" is smaller than  
                 * the Area of the other specified object*/
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool IsLess(Object o)
        {
            if (o is Rectangle)
            {
                if (((Rectangle)o).Area > this.Area)
                /* if the Area of "o" is larger than  
                 * the Area of the other specified object*/
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string returnString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(this.Height); i++)
                /* while i is smaller than the value of Height,rounded up*/ 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Math.Ceiling(this.Width); j++)
                /* while j is smaller than the value of Width,rounded up*/
                {
                    Console.Write("/\\");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return returnString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO the [C# programming guide on properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) explain the very well. Is there anything your not clear on after reading?

Comment: IMO it's bad form to return a different value to the one you set.

Comment: That's really a bad example to teach by, btw. Unless you want to teach how _not_ to do things.

Comment: If Set doesn't set the property. Then it should tell you about it and be a `bool TrySetScale(type Value)`. Or someone is going to scratch their head.. Why is Scale=-1 not working?

Comment: @Fildor Oh? Why do you say so?

Comment: @Mike There are just some basic "No-No"s in there that I - were I the teacher - wouldn't want my students to encounter in _my_ lecture material. _Unless_ the task was to identify and correct them. E.g. declaration of multiple vars in one line = NoNo. Properties returning different result from the value they have been set to = NoNo. Interfaces' names without leading "I" - well, at least disputable. and some more.

Comment: @Fildor Ah ok thanks I see. Actually the multiple var declaration was my thing - I've seen some people on Youtube do it. Why should it be avoided?

Although yeah, the part about returning a different result than it has been set to is kinda weird I don't really get it

Comment: _"Why should it be avoided?"_ - Well, I am not particularly a "because muh holybook"-guy _but_ it's in the MS [layout conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions#layout-conventions). But of course, it has a reason why it has been included. It's not stated there, but I guess it's a mix of readability, explicity (is that a word?) and comfortability to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually properties are the regular methods and that's all.

For example, let's take class with auto-property:

```cs
public class ExampleClass {
  public int ExampleProperty {get;set;}
}
```

it will be compiled into something like this:

```cs
public class ExampleClass {
 private int _exampleProperty;
 public int get_ExampleProperty() { return _a; }
 public void set_ExampleProperty(int value) { _a = value; }
}
```

When you write `Console.WriteLine(exampleClass.ExampleProperty)` it means `Console.WriteLine(exampleClass.get_ExampleProperty())` and for `exampleClass.ExampleProperty = 2` it means `exampleClass.set_ExampleProperty(2)`. So think of them just like of the regular methods.

And example from your code:

```cs
public class Rectangle {
 ...
 public double scale;
 public double Scale
 {
  get { return scale; }
  set { if (value > 0) { scale = value; } }
 }
 ...
}
```

It will be compiled into:

```cs
public class Rectangle {
 ...
 public double scale
 public double get_Scale() { return scale; }
 public void set_Scale(double value) {
  if (value > 0) {
    scale = value
  }
 }
 ...
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var rectangle = new Rectangle(2,2);
rectangle.Scale = 3; // set_Scale(3) call
Console.WriteLine(rectangle.Scale); // get_Scale() call
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this. It's a little clearer now. 

I guess what I also find confusing is that we return a value with get before we set it. So what are we returning then? The default value? And if we are returning this value to simply set a new value, why do we need to return it at all? Why not just set it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. 
1. Yes, if we didn't set any value it'll return default value (e.g null for reference type);
2. What do you mean with this 
_And if we are returning this value to simply set a new value, why do we need to return it at all? Why not just set it?_

Comment: So let's say we've got Scale the property and scale the field. I use `get { return scale; }` first which gets me the default value of scale - then I use `set { scale = value; }` to set scale to a new value, right? 

I just don't know why you need to return the default value in the first place. Unless I'm still not understanding the details of this

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. There's misunderstanding. In my examples I showed you what properties will be **compiled** into. It wasn't usage, it was **declaration** in class.  So, properties are just syntax sugar to use them as **fields** but actually it will be method calls. I think I need to fix my examples

Answer (score 1):

batangaming provides a good explanation on how the properties work under the hood. But I wanted to provide some additional recommendations on how to use properties. While you can do just about anything inside a property setter or getter it is important to consider the users expecations. For example

```
myRectangle.Scale = -1;
```

This will compile and run just fine, but will do nothing, and is probably an error. So it might be better to write the setter as

```
public double Scale
    {
        get { return scale; }
        set { 
             if (value > 0) { scale = value; }
             else{ throw new ArgumentException("Invalid scale value, must be positive");
          }
    }
```

This will ensure the error is noticed and handled.

In the same way if I run the code

```
myRectangle.Width = 10;
Console.WriteLine(myRectangle.Width.ToString());
```

I would expect that the printed value to be 10, but that is not the case if scale != 1. So you might want to divide the value with the scale in the setter.

You might also consider [mutability vs immutability](https://www.csharpstar.com/csharp-immutability/). I.e. if objects are allowed to change after creation or not. My personal preference is to use immutable objects whenever possible. This has a number of advantages:

- Objects are threadsafe per default
- The behavior is identical for both classes (i.e. reference types) and structs (i.e. value types)
- Validation is only needed in the constructor
- It makes it clearer where objects change. I.e. if I give a immutable object to a method I do not have to worry if the object is modified or not by the method.
- It tend to make the code quite compact. For example:

  ```
  public class MyRectangle 
  {
    public double Width { get; }
    public double Height { get; }
    public double Area => Width * Height;
    public MyRectangle Scale(double scale) => new MyRectangle(Width * scale, Height * scale);
    public MyRectangle(double width, double height) => (Width, Height) = (width, height);
  }
  ```

I would also suggest looking into `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IComparer<T>`. Instead of having a `IsGreater` method you define a `AreaComparer` class. This allow you to compare objects in different ways, I.e. you can have both an `AreaComparer` and an `WidthComparer`.